# MPICC and MKL compile

Tags: compiler-construction, mpi

How can I compile my c file ,which I used MKL Blas functions in it, via mpicc ? 
Normally -without MKL-, I compile like this "mpicc -o out main.c". However I can not link while compiling, with MKL. Thanks in advance

Comment: what link error are you getting when you try to link mkl?

Comment: @eduffy Actually I just can not find how to link. There is no word in my hand to write down the compile command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking to MKL is needlessly tricky.   Intel has an "MKL Link Line Advisor" which tries to give you the right linking invocation:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor/